# UNION and intersection using SPARQL queries

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, arq, redland

I am converting user-defined-queries into SPARQL. For example, when user says, "abc", it means give me all nodes of a given type which have some attribute named "abc".  As an extension of this, if user says, "abc or (pqr and lmn)", I need to find all nodes of a given type for which some attribute is "abc or (pqr and lmn)". Following is the query I have come up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?node, ?type                                                 
WHERE                                                                          
{
  {                                                                              
    ?node a ?type .                                                          
    FILTER ( ?type != <sometype>)
  }
{           
  {                                                                              
    ?node ?reln0 ?obj0 .                                                     
    FILTER ( regex(str(?obj0), 'abc', "i") )                           
  }                                                                              
  UNION                                                                          
  {                                                                              
    {                                                                              
      ?node ?reln1 ?obj1 .                                                     
      FILTER ( regex(str(?obj1), 'pqr', "i") )                                
    }
    {                                                                             
      ?node ?reln2 ?obj2 .                                                     
      FILTER ( regex(str(?obj2), 'lmn', "i") )                               
    }                                                                              
  }
}                                                                              
}                                                                              
ORDER BY ?node
```

But it doesn't return proper results. Is there something wrong with the above given query? I don't want to use the following because I need to generate the conditions dynamically and each clause needs to be separate.

```
FILTER (regex(str(?obj2), 'abc', "i") || regex(str(?obj2), 'pqr', "i") && regex(str(?obj2), 'lmn', "i"))
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use the second approach with one big `FILTER`. It's simpler and it works.

Comment: each of the terms can be more complex making the body of the {} bigger and those will be mixed with these basic cases.
FILTER works for only this case.

Comment: Also, I found above query not work on Redland. Then I tried installing ARQ and it worked on it. So, it may be related to that particular implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't return proper results"?

Comment: What version of the Redland libraries (and of ARQ) did you use?  The results I got seemed to be “proper”.  Can you show us any of the data you were working with?

Answer (score 2):

I made your query concrete as follows (putting in a definite type for the first filter):

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?node ?type                                                 
WHERE                                                                          
{
    {                                                                              
        ?node a ?type .                                                          
        FILTER ( ?type != :Type1 )
    }
    {           
        {                                                                              
            ?node ?reln0 ?obj0 .                                                     
            FILTER ( regex(str(?obj0), 'abc', "i") )                           
        }                                                                              
        UNION                                                                          
        {                                                                              
            {                                                                              
                ?node ?reln1 ?obj1 .                                                     
                FILTER ( regex(str(?obj1), 'pqr', "i") )                                
            }
            {                                                                             
                ?node ?reln2 ?obj2 .                                                     
                FILTER ( regex(str(?obj2), 'lmn', "i") )                               
            }                                                                              
        }
    }                                                                              
}                                                                              
ORDER BY ?node
```

I then generated the following data:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .

:n1 a :Type2 ;    # keep
    :r0 :NodeABC .

:n2 a :Type2 ;
    :r0 :NodeBCD .

:n3 a :Type2 ;     # keep
    :r1 :NodePQR ;
    :r2 :NodeLMN .

:n4 a :Type2 ;
    :r1 :NodeQRS ;
    :r2 :NodeLMN .

:n5 a :Type2 ;
    :r1 :NodePQR ;
    :r2 :NodeMNO .

:n6 a :Type2 ;
    :r1 :NodeQRS ;
    :r2 :NodeMNO .
```

Only `:n1` and `:n3` should be kept.  I can run this with [Jena's command line ARQ](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/cmds.html), or the [Redland based `roqet`](http://librdf.org/rasqal/roqet.html), and I get these rules in both cases.

With ARQ:

```
$ arq --data data.n3 --query query.sparql
-----------------
| node | type   |
=================
| :n1  | :Type2 |
| :n3  | :Type2 |
-----------------

$ arq --version
Jena:       VERSION: 2.10.0
Jena:       BUILD_DATE: 2013-02-20T12:04:26+0000
ARQ:        VERSION: 2.10.0
ARQ:        BUILD_DATE: 2013-02-20T12:04:26+0000
```

With `roqet`:

```
$ roqet query.sparql -D data.n3 -r table
roqet: Querying from file query.sparql
--------------------------------------------------------------
| node                       | type                          |
==============================================================
| uri<http://example.org/n1> | uri<http://example.org/Type2> |
| uri<http://example.org/n3> | uri<http://example.org/Type2> |
--------------------------------------------------------------

$ roqet -v
0.9.28
```