# SPARQL : Find Difference and Common Elements in 2 Sets

Tags: sql, rdf, sparql, rdfs

I am a newbie to SPARQL and struggling to achieve these 2 goals and need your help. I have 2 classes where I have stored the keywords of python and CPP respectively. Now I intend to find the common keywords from these 2 sets and also the difference between the 2 (meaning, keywords which exists in python but not in CPP and vice versa). I have tried MINUS and NOT EXISTS version of the queries but to no help.
To find the difference in 2 sets, I tried the below query:

```
SELECT ?subject
    WHERE 
    { ?subject a python:Keywords. 
    { FILTER NOT EXISTS {?subject a cpp:Keywords} }
    }
```

To find the common elements in 2 sets, I tried the below query:

```
select ?subject
where{ ?subject a python:Keywords. FILTER  EXISTS { ?object a cpp:Keywords}
}
```

None of them are working. Please help

Comment: Does `SELECT ?subject WHERE { ?subject a python:Keywords. }` actually return what you expect it to return? And likewise for `cpp:Keywords`? Are these the repective keywords?

Comment: Yes. It returns me a list of all keywords from python and cpp respectively. Now I need to find the commonality and differences between these 2 sets.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ?subject
  WHERE 
  { ?subject a python:Keywords .
    ?subject a cpp:Keywords .
  }
```

should give you the common keywords.

```
SELECT ?subject
  WHERE 
  { ?subject a python:Keywords. 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?subject a cpp:Keywords}
  }
```

should return python keywords, which are not cpp keywords.

Comment: The first query is more succintly: `?subject a python:Keywords, cpp:Keywords`.

Answer (score 1):

### The *problem* in your code

In your first query, the problem is that you've put the filter inside of another set of braces.  That is, you have:

```
SELECT ?subject
    WHERE 
    { ?subject a python:Keywords. 
    { FILTER NOT EXISTS {?subject a cpp:Keywords} }
    }
```

but should have instead:

```
SELECT ?subject
    WHERE 
    { ?subject a python:Keywords. 
      FILTER NOT EXISTS {?subject a cpp:Keywords}
    }
```

The difference is important, because the first is filtering the matches for the enclosing pattern, which doesn't actually have any effect.

### The solution

After that, [Abecee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962222/1281433) is what you need.  The intersection is simply things that are both types:

```
?x a :type1, :type2
```

and the difference is things that are one type but not the other:

```
?x a :type1
filter not exists { ?x a :type2 }
```

### Similar questions and answers

- [Set difference in SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21391444/1281433)
- [UNION and intersection using SPARQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10146576/1281433)